# Equivalent condition of conformality in holomorphic functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. Prove/disprove that for a function $f$ which is holomorphic at $z_0 \in \mathbb C$, $f$ is conformal at $z_0$ if and only if $f'(z_0)\neq 0$.

The implication ''$f'(z_0)\neq 0 \Rightarrow f$ is conformal at $z_0$'' is clear for me since
$$\frac{d}{dz}f(\gamma(t_0))=f'(\gamma(t_0)) \cdot \gamma'(t_0),$$
where, $\gamma$ is a smooth curve passing through $z_0=\gamma(t_0)$, and, the right hand side of above equation describes a composition of rotation and dilation (Jacobian matrix of $f'(z)$) on $\gamma'$. This shows the angle preserving behavior of $f$ at $z_0$.

But how to handle with the second implication ''$f$ is conformal at $z_0\Rightarrow f'(z_0)\neq 0$  ''?

Comment: Why don't you show the contrapositive instead: if $f'(z_0) = 0$, then $f$ is not conformal?

Comment: How can we ensure that $f$ does not preserve angle at $z_0$ when $f'(z_0)=0$. Of course we have examples like $f(z)=z^2$, but I couldn't conform the violation in angle preserving.

Comment: Can we say the multiplication with zero Jacobian matrix should necessarily violate the angle preserving behavior?

Comment: multiplying by $0$ does not preserve angles. It destroys them. They are no longer angles.

Comment: Sir,  What does ''it destroys them" mean?

Comment: Before you multiply by $0$, you have two non-zero vectors, forming the sides of your angle. After you multiply by $0$, you have a single point, the $0$ vector, which has no length and cannot form the side of angle, even with itself. In what sense could you consider that as "preserving angles"? If $f'(z_0) = 0$, then $f$ is not conformal.

Comment: Ya....fine...thnks a lot...

Comment: Sir, Is it pretty similar to the concept of local invertibility in inverse function theorem?

Comment: Conformality $\implies$ local invertibility, but not the other way around. Also, $f' = 0$ means the function is not conformal, but it doesn't necessarily mean the function is not locally invertible. $f(x) = x^3$ is locally invertible around $0$, even though $f'(0) = 0$. The inverse function theorem is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.